# I have two versions of VLC installed on the same system

Tags: vlc

There are two VLCs:

1. VLC (The ultimate media player) - version- 3.0.0
2. VLC media player (Read, capture, broadcast your multimedia streams) - version - 2.2.6-6

I am worried that one of them may be fake. Which one is safe?

Comment: How you installed these packages?

Answer (score 3):

It is simple:

1. VLC 2.2.6-6 is from [official 17.10 Ubuntu repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=vlc):

   check with `apt-cache policy vlc`
2. VLC 3.0.0 may be [a Snap](https://snapcraft.io/vlc)

   check with `snap list | grep vlc`